# Watin's use for Screen Scraping from Hosting Server

Tags: asp.net, screen-scraping, html-agility-pack, watin

I am new to screen scraping and I have some complex needs like logging into a web page then from there I could take help of HtmlAmbiguityPack . 
And for logging purpose I found WatiN very useful , but my doubt is: when I would host my site on a remote server . Could WatiN work from there also as is working on my WINDOWS PC. 
ps: my question could be very silly , so pardon me . and IF you have any ideas for other FRAMEWORKs which could help me in complex needs like logging in , selecting controls, filling text boxes . So please tell me :)

Comment: As long as the remote server is Windows, I don't see why not.

Comment: @pguardiario I have never hosted a site , you might already have figured that :P
So a site like [link](www.FreeHosting.com) what kind of server OS do they use ? how do I know that .

Comment: No, that wouldn't work. You will need direct access with remote desktop or something similar and budget hosts don't offer that.